# Extracting specific elements from Wikipedia tables in Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup

For my own future convenience I have decided to try and create a Java program that can take a directory on my computer and the URL of the Wikipedia entry for a TV show and proceed to rename all the files in that directory with the show name, "S*x*E*y*" and the title of the episode. While I believe I have working code for the renaming of the files, one thing I am stuck with is populating the array that contains the episode names. While this could be done manually, that would eliminate the point of the program in the first place, so I would like to be able to pull the information from the internet.

The TV show in question right now is [Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arrow_episodes), and I'm looking to get the episode names for season 2 right now. I've been attempting to modify [this](https://blog.tallan.com/2012/07/26/parsing-html-using-jsoup-library/) jsoup tutorial to access the tables, hoping to narrow down to the required table once it at least starts to work. My modified code for reference:

```
package tablescraper;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TableScraper {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arrow_episodes").get();
        Elements trs = doc.select("table.wikitable tr");

        //remove header row
        trs.remove(0);

        for (Element tr : trs) {

            Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td.summary");
            Element td = tds.first();
            System.out.println("Episode: " + td.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In it's current state I am faced with a `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `System.out.println("Episode: " + td.toString());`. I attempted to add `.summary` in the `getElementsByTag` statement, hoping that would only pick out the elements that had the "summary" class, which is the one I need.

Have I made an error in my approach so far? Any glaring omissions that I've made? You'll notice that every other row in the tables contains a paragraph summarising the episode - is this change of format part of the problem? Could it grow to become a problem if I'm iterating over each table row as I am now? Moving forward, how am I going to be able to differentiate between each of the tables on the page? If there's no way to differentiate between them for this particular source then that isn't the end of the world, as if necessary I could simply take a list of *all* the episodes and then cut it down to a select range of entries based on the episode numbers needed.

Comment: How do you know it's returning just from season 2? This `doc.select("table.wikitable td.summary")` should return the names from all episodes from all seasons.

Comment: I don't know that it is, but that's my end goal. Right now I imagine it would be looking through all the tables on the page that contain the specified tags, but no luck so far. With your alteration, how would I then output that list of episodes? Would I adjust `tr.getElementsByTag` to `tr.getAllElements`? I'm unfamiliar with this library, but having a list of all the episodes would certainly bring me much closer to my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be tables in the page with class `wikitable` which contain `td` element without class `summary`.

Therefore it is a good idea to insert a null-check before you output the `td`:

```
Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td.summary");
Element td = tds.first();
if (td != null)
    System.out.println("Episode: " + td.toString());
```

Then

```
Elements tds = tr.getElementsByTag("td.summary");
```

will never return a non empty list since there is no element with tag `td.summary`. Again use `select` to look for descendants which match the selector `td.summary`:

```
Elements tds = tr.select("td.summary");
```

Finally to print out the episode (which is the text content of the `td`element) don't use `td.toString()` but `td.text()`

```
System.out.println("Episode: " + td.text());
```

Comment: Ok so I've made this change, and now the error is gone, however the code returns no results. Is it possible that it's only looking at the first item in the row and then, upon seeing that it isn't of class `summary`, moving to the next row?

Comment: @SimonB there is an issue with `tr.getElementsByTag("td.summary")`. See my edited post,

Comment: ah I see that now. With this change the program is now outputting the whole html for that entry, for example the second line of output is Episode: <td class="summary" style="text-align:left">"Honor Thy Father"</td>`. Excluding the "Episode: " bit, I guess now I can just use substrings to remove everything before `>"` and after `"<`, right? The first line doesn't follow this format, but I can correct for that later.

Comment: That works brilliantly, thank you. The `for` loop now looks like this, with adjustments made to get rid of the speech marks: `for (Element tr : trs) {

                Elements tds = tr.select("td.summary");
                Element td = tds.first();
                if(td != null){
                    String episode = td.text();
                    episode = episode.substring(1, episode.lastIndexOf('"'));
                    System.out.println("Episode: " + episode);
                }
                
            }`